Image Classification Model halting at epoch 1/25, tensorflow keras model
I have been following a tutorial of a deep learning neural network model project and for some reason my model halts at the first epoch when trying to train on a dataset of images. I am not sure if this is a problem with my version of tensorflow(I am running on python 3.9.12) or if it is a problem with the cpu not being able to process everything. My dataset includes about 8000 image files belonging to 70 classes. I am also receiving this error:
Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
Here is the code of my python file:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential


data_training_path = '/training_path'
data_testing_path = '/testing_path'
data_validation_path = '/validation_path'

image_width = 180
image_height = 180
batch_size = 16

data_train = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_training_path, 
    shuffle=True,
    image_size=(image_width, image_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=None
)

data_test = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_testing_path, 
    shuffle=False,
    image_size=(image_width, image_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=None
)

data_val = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_validation_path, 
    shuffle=False,
    image_size=(image_width, image_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=None
)

data_classes = data_train.class_names

print("Training data classes:", data_classes)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

for images, labels in data_train.take(1):
    print("Batch of images shape:", images.shape)
    print("Batch of labels shape:", labels.shape)
    for i in range(min(9, len(images))):
        plt.subplot(3, 3, i+1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype('uint8'))
        plt.title(data_classes[labels[i]])
        plt.axis('off')

plt.show()

model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(len(data_classes), activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False), metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs_size = 25

print("Number of batches in training data:", tf.data.experimental.cardinality(data_train).numpy())
print("Number of batches in validation data:", tf.data.experimental.cardinality(data_val).numpy())

history = model.fit(
    data_train, 
    validation_data=data_val, 
    epochs=epochs_size, 
    verbose=1)


Did you tried to test with a smaller dataset (e.g., subsample of the one your are using) to check if the code is functional?

@K.Bogdan yes, but the same error still arises

Which TF version are you using? Check this question too, it seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376338/while-training-dl-model-local-rendezvous-is-aborting-with-status-out-of-range

I replicated your code on a dataset with 5,000 images, and it worked
successfully, achieving 94% accuracy by increasing the number of epochs. I'm
using Google Colab,please refer to this gist.  Please let me know if you're still facing any issues.
